# Unable to convert a string to the desired regexp in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I do have the following string:

```
"/^\d{4}$/"
```

which I want to convert to a RegExp to use the test method on it.
However, simply doing :

```
var r = new RegExp("/^\d{4}$/") // returns : /\/^\d{4}$\//
r.test("4800") // returns false
```

isn't working.

I also tried the following :

```
var r = /^\d{4}$/
r.test("4800") // returns true
```

which is working

What am I missing here ? How to have it working in the first case with a string.

Comment: Remove `/` from start and end. RegExp adds it automatically. You need to pass pattern to it. So `new RegExp("^\d{4}$")`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: try this var r = new RegExp(/^\d{4}$/)

Comment: `r=new RegExp("/^\\d{4}$/")` or just `r=/^\d{4}$/` As per documentation

Comment: Oh, come on. The right one with a constructor notation: `new RegExp("^\\d{4}$")`. Do not use `new RegExp(/^\d{4}$/)` as it is not supported in all browsers.